# How to convert NSView to CALayer?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-animation, calayer, nsview

I have made a video player,and images are draw in a NSView.Have any method to convert NSView to CALayer?I try to use **layer-hosting view**,but developer document said **can not add any subviews to layer-hosting view**.Anyone can give me some suggestions?This code can run in OSX 10.6.8,but OSX 10.7 and 10.8.

```
mDisplayView = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, width, height)];
mDisplayLayer = [[CALayer layer] retain];

[mDisplayView setLayer:mDisplayAudioLayer];
[mDisplayView setWantsLayer:YES];
[mDisplayView addSubview:mContentView];
[mRootLayer addSublayer:mDisplayAudioLayer];
```

The image of video had been drawn on **mContentView**.I just need find a way to make the **mContentView** into **CALayer**,is that possible？

Answer (score 2):

You do not *convert* a view to a layer - you either draw into a view traditionally by overriding `drawRect:` or you switch it to layer-backed view and use CoreAnimation.

Best to start here to understand the basic concepts involved:

[**Core Animation Programming Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: On the other hand, if the questioner is using AVPlayerLayer, he or she probably should not be adding it as a sublayer of the layer of a layer-backed view, because [\[y\]ou should rarely, if ever, directly modify the layer that is attached to \[a\] layer-backed NSView”](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CreatingBasicAnimations/CreatingBasicAnimations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH3-SW18). Layer-hosting is the correct way to go in that case. (But you're still right about “converting” views to layers.)

Comment: True. But my impression was that the basic concepts of how to use views and layers isn't entirely clear to the OP.. Probably not surprising the way CA is bolted on top of AppKit on OS X.